# MCImage Manager handling 2 websites with common folder

Tags: tinymce, mcimagemanager

My Requirements

1. Implement MCImageManager so that users can upload images to a
   "centralized" folder
2. Allow users to select an imagae on the centralized "ImageLibrary" and place it on a web page or blog post

IMPORTANT:

There's one challange that I need to find a solution for. Typically images are placed in a folder that exists in the website e.g. ~/Images or ~/Content/Images

The challange we have is that I will be having, however web pages will be displayed through separate websites. More specifically, in a typical scenario, a user would upload an image through MCIMageManager that places the file in a folder in the web application. So the image may be uploaded to a folder like D:\xyz\ImageLibrary.

However, the root folder may be F:\ on an entirely different server.

Therefore we need to come up with a way to share image folders between two websites so that regardless of where the image folder may be, the image will display correctly both on xyz web site management module AND the actual website.

Regards

Abhishek

Answer (score 0):

For this use case you should mount the upload directory of server A to the upload directory of server B.

Comment: you will need to use softlinks in oprder to point to the same cebntralized image directory.